# Base field defined as entity reference with cardinality unlimited, only allowing one entry

Tags: entities, 9

I have defined a custom entity type "Event" and I want a field on it called "Attendees" which should allow the user to enter multiple attendees.

I have defined the field thus:

```
   $fields['attendees'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Attendees'))
  ->setDescription(t('People attending this event.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'oc_actor')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => 50,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete_tags',
    'weight' => 50,
  ])
  ->setRequired(FALSE);
```

However, the resulting field does not have unlimited cardinality. It only allows the user to enter one attendee. Compare and contrast with the "Test" field that I added beneath it using the GUI:

[image]

I have done a fresh install of the whole site since I last touched this code so it is not a matter of needing to add an update hook or clear the cache or anything like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any idea why this was downvoted? It looks like a pretty clear question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it set to entity_reference_autocomplete_tags which means the multiple values end up comma separated. You probably want just entity_reference_autocomplete.